# c# webdriver selenium click not working for html table with onclick

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have html table on which it has javascript onclick function.I am facing problem with selenium click method.

```
<table id="somedynamicID" onclick="PerformClick();" class="Level2Item" >
<tbody>
    <tr><td ><img src="imagePath" alt=""></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="100%" nowrap="" id="somedynamicID" >Link Text</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

below is the code snippet I am using to perform Click.

```
Table = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Level2Item"));
IWebElement myrow = Table.FirstOrDefault(td => td.Text.Contains("Link Text"));
myrow.Click();
```

above code is not working please help me.

Comment: It is not working how? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: we are getting error in run mode "System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object." but in debug mode it works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
var Table = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Level2Item"));
IWebElement myrow = Table.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(), 'Link Text')]"));
myrow.Click();
```

Comment: can we do something like                                                                    IWebElement myrow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[contains(@class,'Level2Item')] /tr/td[contains(text(), 'Link Text')]")); myrow.Click();

Comment: then you have to use like `IWebElement myrow = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[@class='Level2Item']//tr/td[contains(text(), 'Link Text')]"));`

Comment: Hi Pranav do we need to put wait to run this code as it working in debug mode but in run mode getting error.

Comment: it depends on your page load time, if required then you can use `driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));`

Comment: We are getting this error " Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with".

Comment: Thanks Pranav work for me

    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
    var Table = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("Level2Item"));
    IWebElement myrow = Table.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[contains(text(), 'Link Text')]"));
    myrow.Click();

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this :

```
public static bool FindInTableAndClick(IWebDriver driver, string TableID, string StrToFind)
    {
        IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table[contains(@id, '" + TableID + "')]"));
        ICollection<IWebElement> trCollection = tableElement.FindElements(By.XPath("id('" + tableElement.GetAttribute("id") + "')/tbody/tr"));
        ICollection<IWebElement> tdCollection = null;

        foreach (var tr in trCollection)
        {
            if (tdCollection != null)
            {
                foreach (var td in tdCollection)
                {
                    if (td.Text.ToLower().Contains(StrToFind.ToLower()))
                    {
                        td.Click();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        return false;
    }
```